# Cannot find toolbar in header - blender 2.8

Tags: python, interface, edit-mode

[image]

Hi,

I cannot find the toolbar in my blender and when I search toolbar it shows like this in the second image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click (RMB) on any button in 3D-view header and in menu find **Show Tool Settings**

[image]

Comment: OMG YOU JUST SAVED MY LIFE! THANK YOU SIR!

Comment: oh, by the way, in recent builds this option also located in _View_ menu. And don't forget to accept the answers https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the header, you just have to click and drag down the square with an arrow that is seen in the upper right part of the viewport, where I have indicated it in the image, and the headers will appear.

**You can see the image here:**

[image: http://prntscr.com/s2kjw0]

Comment: Hi, could you possibly **not use random image services and instead use the tools that are built into Blender Stackexchange**? Random image/file services won't keep those images for long and your answer would be useless without it.